# C++ curly brace inside parentheses

Tags: c++, gcc-statement-expression

I countered the following code for the first time. I am confused about its syntax and why it would work.

```
int b = ({
        int c = 2;
        c;
    });
std::cout << b;
```

Comment: It's a GNU/g++ extension and is known as a *statement expression*. Looking for a suitable duplicate ...

Comment: I'm wondering why does that pass clang++ without a warning.

Comment: In any case: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html

Comment: @Elazar Well, clang-cl gives me: *warning : use of GNU statement expression extension [-Wgnu-statement-expression]*

Comment: You can compile with `-pedantic` to get warnings about non-standard extension. In this case, you'd get the warning  _"warning: use of GNU statement expression extension [-Wgnu-statement-expression]"_.